# What is the mount on this Elicar 85-205mm F3.8 lens?

Tags: lens-mount, vintage, equipment-identification

What is the mount on this Elicar Auto Zoom lens , 85-205mm F3.8 No. 493302?
[image][image][image][image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like several other brands sold that lens ... if it IS identical to what vivitar sold, you got a Kino Precision lens here, which made some of the better (bulky, heavy, overly complicated but optically not too shabby) early tele zooms.

Comment: Yep, 13 elements in 9 groups for a mid 1960s design... there's your heavy and complicated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an old Minolta SR mount lens. The notch in the bayonet tab in your 4th and 5th pictures are a dead giveaway for being a Minolta SR/MC/MD mount.

The lack of a shutter-preferred autoexposure lug means it is not an MD lens. The riveted tab is the meter coupling tab, indicating this is an MC lens.

See also:

- [Minolta SLR Lens Mounts](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126214639/http://www.subclub.org/minman/mounts.htm)
- [Minolta SR-mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_SR-mount) (Wikipedia)